# Getting OutOfBound exception

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a java program which stores telephone directory information in an array. Whenever I am trying to put some entries inside this array, I get OutOfBound exception.

```
private int size = 0;
private Entry[] entryList = new Entry[size];

public ArrayDirectory(){

}

@Override
public void Add(String surName, String initials, int telNumber) {

    entryList[size] = new Entry(surName, initials, telNumber);
    size++;


}

    public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayDirectory directory = new ArrayDirectory();

    directory.Add("Charles", "Johnson", 1234);

    System.out.println(directory.entryList.length);
}
```

Thank you for your attention

Comment: arrays are static in general you are trying to allocate the size dynamically. Because of this i am getting outofboundexception.

Comment: look at the first 2 lines of your program...

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are fixed size. As soon as you create them with a set size that is the maximum number of elements they can hold.

```
private int size = 0;
private Entry[] entryList = new Entry[size];
```

You creating an array with size 0 which means no elements can be set in it.

```
private int size = 5;
```

Will allow you to put a maximum of 5 elements into it using indexes: `0,1,2,3,4`

A better solution would be to use a dynamic array through an `ArrayList`. This will dynamically resize when more elements are added.

```
List<Entry> entryList = new ArrayList<Entry>();

entryList.add(new Entry());
```

Comment: Thank you very much mate, this is an Uni assignment and the teacher has told us to use arrays instead of ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

An array can't be extends dynamically like an `ArrayList`. You initialized an array of size 0, which will never be able to hold any elements.

So, either use an `ArrayList`, which will increase in size dynamically, or initialize your array with the maximum amount of space you want / may spent.

Answer (score 0):

At very beginning of your code, you have this

```
private int size = 0;
private Entry[] entryList = new Entry[size];
```

It means, you create array of size 0, therefore that array does not have any "cell", and accessing any values resulting in exception.